# ValueError at /register/ The view authenticate.views.register_user didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms

I am not able to fix this problem, this  everytime showing `views.register_user` didn't return an httpresponse. Also registering of  user not happening properly, everytime this showing  above error text. Yesterday it was working properly but today showing error. So, how to fix this error and how ro solve this problem? I have posted my detail code, please look up. Also I have applied in stackoverflow answers but nothing working.

Below my code:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import SignUpForm

def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password = password)
            login(request,user)
            messages.success(request,('You Have Been Registered!'))
            return redirect('home')
        
    
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request,'authenticate/register.html',context)
```

register.html

```
{% extends 'authenticate/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h2 class="text-center">Register</h2>
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
    <form method="POST" action ="{% url 'register' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}

            {% if form.errors %}

                       
                        <p>Your Form Has Errors.....</p>
                        
               


            {% endif %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-secondary">
   </form>

</div>
<br/><br/>
{% endblock  %}
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label="",widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Email Address'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(label="",max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'First Name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(label="",max_length=100,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Last Name'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','first_name','last_name','email','password1','password2')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(SignUpForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

         self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
         self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'User Name'
         self.fields['username'].label=""
         self.fields['username'].help_text='<span class="form-text text-muted"><small>Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.</small></span>'
        
         self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
         self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Password'
         self.fields['password1'].label=""
         self.fields['password1'].help_text='<ul class="form-text text-muted"><li>Your password can’t be too similar to your other personal information.</li><li>Your password must contain at least 8 characters.</li><li>Your password can’t be a commonly used password.</li><li>Your password can’t be entirely numeric.</li></ul>'
        
         self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
         self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Confirm Password'
         self.fields['password2'].label=""
         self.fields['password2'].help_text='<span class="form-text text-muted"><small>Enter the same password as before, for verification.</small></span>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the form is not valid. In that case you should *rerender* the template with the same form, such that it can display the errors, so:

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, ('You Have Been Registered!'))
            return redirect('home')

    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'authenticate/register.html', context)
```

authenticating however makes not much sense: you *create* a user here, so you can log in that user immediately:

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, ('You Have Been Registered!'))
            return redirect('home')

    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'authenticate/register.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: While most forms do not process media files, it is probably better to pass [**`request.FILES`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) to the form anyway, such that if you later add an extra media field, all views that use the form will indeed handle the files properly.